# How to display comma tags from mysql to blade view

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I have a table that has a "tags" column with the following data:

```
| tags      |
|-----------|
| baby,test |
| color     |
| test,good |
```

On my blade view I want to display them on a dropdown menu.

Output should be something like this:

```
baby
test
color
good
```

what I tried so far:

```
$tags = Article::all('tags');
$arr = collect(explode(',' , $tags));
```

but it messing up the values.

Comment: `$tags = Article::get();` `$arr = explode(',' , $tags->tags);`

Comment: I recommend creating a new table called `tags` and creating a many-to-many relationship. Would make this much easier.

Comment: You really should consider normalizing your schema. Read why [storing a delimited string in a database is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad).

Comment: Hello, @El_Vanja thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, I don't have access to the back-end since it was the other developer who made it.  I have successfully removed the commas but the output went something like this. [baby test, color, test good]

Comment: Have you attempted Espresso's suggestion from the first comment?

Comment: Yes, @El_Vanja unfortunately its also not working.

Comment: I have managed to make it work. Thank you so much for helping. Cheers! @El_Vanja Espresso ,Aless55

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$tags = explode(",",Article::pluck("tags")->implode(','));

dd($tags);
```

Output will be tags in array

Comment: I want to display them like what I mentioned above. but thank you for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Dear it will make each tag a item in array then use it with foreach llop as per your requirement then the dd() method use to debug and see what we have proper output or not just use this function it will help you to show what you want

Comment: Do not use dd method and use $tags you will have all the tags itemwise in array

Comment: Hello, I tried your code and made a few tweaks and it's now working fine. Thank you so much for making the time to answer my question. Cheers!